# Select records randomly and different from previously selected records

Tags: php, mysql, api, mysqli, pdo

I have a table with 8,000 Records, I want to select randomly some records (for example 10) from this table. These records have to be different from  previously selected records.

For example with this query I select some questions:

```
SELECT coloumn1,column2 FROM `myTable` WHERE `status`=1 AND `group`=6 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, :max
```

Now how can I select new records randomly and different from previously selected records?

Comment: So effectively you want to select 10 random records but not include any of the same records that were selected before?

Comment: yes, but records can be 10 or more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply you could store the id's of previously selected records and then add to your next query like below, to avoid selecting them twice:

```
WHERE id NOT IN = (list of ids)
```

Based on you'r example:

```
SELECT coloumn1,column2 FROM `myTable` WHERE `status`=1 AND `group`=6 AND id NOT IN (_IDS_) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0
```

Comment: in this case if we have 7,000 selected records before this query, we must add 7,000 id in "(_ID_)" section.
that's doesn't too slow ?

Comment: You could store already selected id's in some temporary table and then instead putting list of id's you could put a subquery instead of it for example: `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM temp);`

Comment: @Tomasz Or simply add a column to the table with a boolean value, set it to "true" after it's been pulled and then during the query ignore any of them that already have this boolean set to true. This has the benefit of not needing the overhead of a whole extra table just for this task. Though using `insert` MAY be faster, but I'm not really sure

Answer (score 0):

try :
    SELECT coloumn1, column2 FROM `myTable` WHERE `status`=1 AND `group`=6 
AND coloumn1 NOT IN (id,id,id,id,ids concatenated in php)
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, :max

and also in select, better select a column that is unique identifier for the row, and use that column with the NOT IN ()

- avoid RAND() as its extremely slow - better work around it with php

If the number of selected records is too big, put them in a temp table, and use

NOT IN (SELECT id FROM temp table...)

Comment: in this case if we have 7,000 selected records before this query, we must add 7,000 id in "(_ID_)" section.
that's doesn't too slow ?

Comment: alternatively put selected records in a temp table and use NOT IN (SELECT ...FROM... tmp_selected_rows WHERE..)